# Two questions about Riesz-Thorin interpolation and log-convexity of $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

The Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem gives us the following:

Let $I=(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ where $I$ can be infinite. 
if we have $0<p_0<p_1<\infty$, and $p_0<p<p_1$ then for some parameter $t\in (0,1)$, and 
$f\in L^{p_0}(I)\cap L^{p_1}(I)$, we obtain the inequality 
$||f||_{L^p_t}\leq ||f||_{p_0}^{1-t}||f||_{p_1}^{t}$

I am aware of the Holder's inequality proof, but what about the following situation:

Question 1:

If we have $\int_{I}|f(x)|^{p_0}$ and $\int_{I}|f(x)|^{p_1}$, I want to show that we also have $\int_{I}|f(x)|^p$. I am *sure* there is some clever substitution trick, but I am just not seeing it.

Question 2:

Similarly, I believe we can also derive the inequality $(\int_{I}|f|^p)^{1/p}\leq (\int_{I}|f|^{p_0})^{\frac{1-t}{p_0}}(\int_{I}|f|^{p_1})^{\frac{t}{p_1}}$ similarly, and again, I am just not seeing the substitution trick.

Comment: Regarding question 1, when you "have a number", do you mean it is finite? And therefore solving question 2 solves question 1?